# Rails API: Netflix fast_jsonapi and Rails render - double data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fastjsonapi

I am building a Rails API and am using Netflix's `fast_jsonapi` code to serialize my `ActiveRecord` objects:

```
class PerformancesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    render json: serialize(user.performances)
  end

  def serialize(data)
    PerformanceSerializer.new(data).serialized_json
  end

end
```

However, when the response returns, I have to access the data with `response.data.data`: 
[image]

This just seems awkward to me. Is there anyway to remove one of the data's?

Comment: Fast_jsonapi serializes payload according to OpenApi standard. So the payload is put under 'data' key. Seems you're using an HTTP library in your client that puts the response body under 'data' too (like Axios). Thus you have the duplication. You can change to a different lib, which maybe use a different key like 'body'. But I wouldn't bother if I were you.

Comment: Ahhhh I am using axios. I never thought to look at the js library. Much appreciated!